# PalindromeCheck efficiency for Int in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, palindrome

I have constructed two ways to check palindrome of a number. Which one is more efficient? By efficiency, I mean in terms of execution time and memory allocations.

First, I convert an Integer to string and check if it is a palindrome. The example of code is as follow.

```
public class Palindrome{

/*
Function palindromeCheck
Return type boolean
Parameters characterArray

Checks character array for palindrome
*/
 public static boolean palindromeCheck(char[] palinCheck){
    boolean palindrome = true;
    int firstLen = 0;
    int secondLen = palinCheck.length - 1;
    while(palindrome == true && firstLen < secondLen ){
        if(palinCheck[firstLen] != palinCheck[secondLen]){
            palindrome = false;
        }
        else{
            firstLen++;
            secondLen--;
        }
    } //end of while
    return palindrome;
} 

/*Main Function
Calls palinDromeCheck function
Prints results
*/
public static void main(String[] args){

    int palinCheck = 1221;
    String dipendra = Integer.toString(palinCheck);
    char[] dipendraChar = dipendra.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(palindromeCheck(dipendraChar));

}
}
```

The second method is without converting it to string.

```
public class PalindromeNumber{


/*
    Function: PalindromeCheck
    parameters integer
    ReturnType: boolean

    Takes integer, checks if it is palindrome and returns accordingly
*/
public static boolean palindromeCheck(int number){
    int firstNumber = number;
    int secondNumber = 0;

    while(number >= 1){
        secondNumber = secondNumber* 10 + (number%10);
        number = number/10;
    }

    return (firstNumber==secondNumber) ? true:false;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(palindromeCheck(111));
}
}
```

Comment: For testing which one is more efficient in terms of execution time, why not try [jmh](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the second algorithm would be faster, and obviously more space efficient. If you assume *n* be the number of digits of the input number, in the first algorithm:

- `Integer.toString` requires *n* steps to convert it to `String`.
- `palindromeCheck` requires *n / 2* comparisons to check whether it's a palindrome.

But, the second algorithm would require *n* steps to compute the reverse number (involving only integer operations) and only 1 comparison to check.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try.
On the following example (with one specific number, on my specific machine...) :

- 580 ms - Your first solution
- 323 ms - Your second solution
- 1045 ms - BrentR's solution

Note I modified the code a bit (but not the logic). You should also take care of spaces and indentation.

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static boolean isPalindrome1(int n) {
        char a[] = Integer.toString(n).toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        int j = a.length - 1;

        while (i < j) {
            if (a[i++] != a[j--]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome2(int n) {
        int p = n, q = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            q = 10 * q + n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return p == q;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome3(int n) {
         String s = Integer.toString(n);
         return s.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int m = 10000000;
        long t1, t2;
        boolean q;

        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
            q = isPalindrome1(123454321);
        }
        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t2 - t1);

        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
            q = isPalindrome2(123454321);
        }
        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t2 - t1);

        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
            q = isPalindrome3(123454321);
        }
        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t2 - t1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you re-inventing the wheel?

java.lang.StringBuilder already provides a string reverse method

```
String string = Integer.toString(10101);

boolean palindrome = string.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString());
```

Comment: Simpler, but slower. If the application does not need the extra speed it's nice. Note that it's slightly faster to use `equals` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: Noted.  Nice analysis. :)